# How to install openpyxl on heroku

Tags: python, heroku

i want to install openpyxl on my heroku but ERROR appears

> remote:          Downloading openpyxl-3.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (243
> kB) remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the
> requirement threading (from versions: none) remote:        ERROR: No
> matching distribution found for threading remote:  !     Push
> rejected, failed to compile Python app. remote:  remote:  !     Push
> failed remote: Verifying deploy...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show your `requirements.txt` and / or `Pipfile`. It looks like you may have defined a dependency on a module from the standard library.

Comment: Check required packages with "pip freeze"

Copy the content to requirements.txt
I succeeded